# What is the meaning of `const func: (num: number) => string = String;` in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, ecmascript-6

I am reading [2ality blog post on TypeScript](http://2ality.com/2018/04/type-notation-typescript.html) and I came across the following code -

```
const func: (num: number) => string = String;
```

I don't understand the meaning of this syntax.

In [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), it compiles to -

```
var func = String;
```

From what I understand, `func` is a function which takes a parameter `num` and the function itself returns a `string` and the `func` variable is assigned to `String` so the whole function thing becomes useless which means the above thing could've been written as simple as -

```
const func = String;
```

Am I correct? Or am I understanding Typescript wrong?

Comment: You're right. `: (num: number) => string` just define typing to the function `func` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically saying `func` is a function (denoted by `x => y`) which takes variable named `num` of type `number` as input, and returns a `string`. In this case the value of function is assigned to the [function `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), which is a constructor function.

In the end, `func` is a new name given to `String` constructor such that it only accepts numeric input. So `func(5)` would be equivalent to `String(5)` and it would return "5".

Notice that the string `(num: number) => string` denotes the schema of function being declared.

Comment: Thanks, Nisarg for editing the post so many times. `In the end, func is a new name given to String constructor` this made it clear :)

Answer (score 2):

> const func: (num: number) => string = String;

This means there is a variable `func` whose type is `(num: number) => string` with value as String class.

Now string constructor accepts a value and returns a string value.

---

For people that are confused between `string` and `String`

- `string`: refers to string value. So `() => string` means a function returning a string. In `var a = 'abc'`, a is a string
- `String`: Note capital `S`. That refers to string constructor, which is a function.

Following is the definition of `String`:
[image]

Comment: The types don't match. One is a function and the oder is a string. Why is there no type error in typescript.

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh. Finally got it :)

Comment: @yonexbat FYI, `string !== String`

Comment: @Rajesh: Tnx. Now I understand this code :). String is a function (constructor) that returns a string if invoked with a number.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function which converts a passed `Number` to a `String`.

You can see that if you enter the following TypeScript:

```
const func: (num: number) => string = String;
console.log(func(123));
console.log(typeof func(123));
console.log(typeof 123);
```

It compiles to:

```
var func = String;
console.log(func(123));
console.log(typeof func(123));
console.log(typeof 123);
```

And executing this code shows `123`, `string` and `number`:

```js
var func = String;
console.log(func(123));
console.log(typeof func(123));
console.log(typeof 123);
```

So, `func` in the above example is returning `new String(num)`, which is why `123` is a number, but `func(123)` is a string.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. The example was helpful to understand :)